# Remove borders in a series of images

Tags: image-processing, image

I have a series of mouse MRI images, here are two

[image]

[image]

How can I automatically remove the metal cage around the mouse to make it look like this:

[image]

The position of the cage is not always in exactly the same position. Making the image more horizontal would also be nice. Also each image should have the same dimensions.

```
image1 = Import["http://i.imgur.com/iGia7W6.jpg"]
```

Answer (score 7):

You could use `ImageLines` to locate the straight edges:

```
image1 = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/xni6T.jpg"];
lines = ImageLines[EdgeDetect@image1, MaxFeatures -> 4];
Show[image1, Graphics[{Thick, Orange, Line /@ lines}]]
```

[image]

Then `ImageRotate` to straighten the image, and then re-detect the lines:

```
image1 = ImageRotate[image1, Pi - Mean[ArcTan @@@ Subtract @@@ lines], Full];
lines = ImageLines[EdgeDetect@image1, MaxFeatures -> 4];
Show[image1, Graphics[{Thick, Orange, Line /@ lines}]]
```

[image]

Then isolate the two inner lines and trim the image:

```
lines = SortBy[lines, #[[1, 2]] &][[{2, 3}]];
ImageTrim[image1, Flatten[lines, 1]]
```

[image]